# How to test IP-based geolocation (need to test various US states, not just lower 48)

Tags: testing, geolocation, maxmind, ip-geolocation

We are looking at implementing an IP-based geolocation service.

At this point, it looks like we'll be using a 3rd party DB, MaxMind's GeoIP2 Enterprise (https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-enterprise-database) and a webservice.

We only need to geolocate by **US state** (and not just lower 48).

What is going to be the easiest way to test this from various states within the US?  Developers are going to need to test **as well as non-developers, i.e., marketing types**.

Are there any 3rd party, web-based solutions we could subscribe to?  I found one that took screenshots (https://www.geoscreenshot.com/capture), but I think we're going to need the ability (for marketing) to interact/navigate around. Something where you just enter an url and then it proxies that through an iframe might be ideal. I'm just wondering how non-developers can easily test IP-based geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the geolocation from multiple country using http://www.locabrowser.com.

The pro is this web site is free service to test from 15 countries without any setup required.

The con is it does not has different states in United States at this moment.

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for, though as you said it doesn't let you browse from different states within the US which is what we need to test.  I also can't seem to navigate around once inside our site.  The general idea of that service is what I think we might need, though.  We're OK with paying for a service as well.